# Frustrating New Job, Should I leave or Should I Discover More?

Tags: new-job, job-change, job-satisfaction

I am currently abroad doing some knowledge transfer on client's site abroad.

When I took off, I went with a plan and a specific area to focus on.

A couple of weeks later, I was told to prepare some presentation for some peers (it felt like baby spooning), and, suddenly,  I was assigned two more areas.

Since this moment, I became lost and lost the eagerness to do the great job I am used to doing. As a matter of fact, I just want to leave.

Moreover, I realized that the projects I am working on have some obsolete technologies (+too much to do for small changes), which is a mismatch with the job offer description I applied to in the first place.

Is it okay to apply in the middle of knowledge transfer or is it harmful for my image?

Comment: You should quit your job today. Apply at a random factory nearby and work the assembly line. The stuff you do on a daily basis is always the same and it's predictable as it will not change :) That way, there will never be a mismatch with the job offer description.

Comment: Your comment is pointless. Actually, I should have stayed in my previous job. I am doing something I didn't sign up to doing, because I was kind of lied to. I asked a colleague of mine about what he described during the interview, and he said that the project was cancelled and that he was sorry.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it okay to apply in the middle of knowledge transfer or is it harmful for my image?

If you were to do this, it'd be somewhat of a red mark on your CV for a while, and the question of why you were only at this particular job a few weeks would come up time and time again. It's not necessarily insurmountable in and of itself, but your reasoning seems to be along the lines of "I've been assigned tasks that mean I'm working with technologies that I don't like" - I wouldn't see that as a great reason for quitting any job a few weeks in. Priorities change, tasks change, roles change, and you can't just expect to be working with the exact technologies listed on the job description and nothing else; life's just not like that!

If in a year or so you're still unhappy, you've talked to your boss about it and it looks like nothing's changed or about to change, then that's a different story.

There are occasions where leaving a few weeks in might be justified - clear cases of bullying or harassment that can't be resolved, or a job description that's nothing like the actual job (employed as a programmer and just cleaning & making the tea.) However, I certainly wouldn't count working with obsolete technologies amongst them.

Comment: +1 Obsolete tech is a fact of life, the OP pretty much has to learn to enjoy  (or at least tolerate) dealing with it to last any length of time in most companies. And I'd be very surprised if a job description was that specific up front.

Comment: @JuliaHayward Agreed - I've seen job descriptions list generic technology stacks that may be used by the company / department, but never a guarantee that "your particular role will use this stack and nothing else".

Answer (score 1):

Quitting while you are abroad at a client's site has two problems: One, you are really letting your company down. Normally leaving your company anytime is no big deal, if they can't handle you leaving that's their fault. In this case it damages your company's reputation with the client, plus will cause mayor inconvenience to that client. That's burning bridges and damaging your reputation. Two, you are abroad in an environment that is foreign to you. You might not feel like that about your job when you are back home and might regret having quit when you are back home.

Unless you are expected to be abroad for a long time, I'd wait until I'm back home and in my usual environment for a few weeks and see how you feel about it then. If that's not what you want to do, I recommend to talk to your company and decide together what is a good time to leave.